# Ubuntu 15.10 & Globalsat BT-338 Bluetooth GPS - org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, bluetooth, gps

I'm trying to get my bluetooth GPS connected to my Asus EEE PC 1201PN.

I've used both the internal bluetooth module, as well as a USB bluetooth module with the same results. I also booted off a thumb drive with 14.04.3 LTS, and was able to connect and receive GPS signal.

**rfkill:**

```
root@hamshacknetbook ~ # rfkill list
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**bluetoothctl:**

```
root@hamshacknetbook ~ # bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 1C:4B:D6:11:4F:2F hamshacknetbook [default]
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 1C:4B:D6:11:4F:2F Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 BT-GPS-305D44
[bluetooth]# scan off
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 RSSI is nil
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Controller 1C:4B:D6:11:4F:2F Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# pair 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 
Attempting to pair with 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 0000
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 
Attempting to connect to 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 00:0D:B5:30:5D:44 Connected: no
```

**Modules:**

```
root@hamshacknetbook ~ # lsmod | grep rf
rfcomm                 69632  2
bluetooth             516096  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
root@hamshacknetbook ~ # lsmod | grep bt
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             516096  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
```

**More output:**

```
root@hamshacknetbook ~ # lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet [1969:1062] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:14e5]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1a3b:1089]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5702 IMC Networks UVC VGA Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0b05:1788 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-270 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
bluetooth             516096  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
[    0.131792] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   12.752756] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   12.752868] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.754760] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.754778] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.754815] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.309091] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.309104] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.309125] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.991372] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.991400] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.991423] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

This is a fairly fresh install, and updated as of last night.

Can anyone give me any hints about how to troubleshoot the bluez "NotAvailable" error?

Update: I upgraded to 16.04 LTS, and the issue remains.

Thanks.